# websocket connection with local server

Tags: websocket, localhost

need to enable websocket connection. already enabled php_sockets.dll extension from php.ini file. and testing with Chrome-extension "WebSocket" with ws://127.0.0.1:6000 but still showing connection status closed. how to connect with localhost

Comment: You'll get better advice if you [edit] your question to show your php code.

Comment: curently testing using only wih chrome extension with localhost.. by ptting localhost url.